# angular e2e test (protractor) needs to import module

Tags: angular, protractor, vmware-clarity

Using the VMware Clarity framework, I want to include responsive behavior. Clarity requires that you use their angular components `clr-main-container` and `clr-header` in the application layout

Now, my e2e tests (with Protractor) are failing because they don't recognize those angular components. I have a single simple e2e test looking for some login text.

`app.e2e-spec.ts`:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging } from 'protractor';

describe( 'workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach( () => {
    page = new AppPage();
  } );

  it( 'should display login page', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect( page.getLoginTitleText() ).toEqual( 'Welcome to\nApp\nClick below to sign in with Google' );
  } );
```

and `app.po.ts`:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  public navigateTo() {
    return browser.get( browser.baseUrl ) as Promise<any>;
  }

  public getLoginTitleText() {
    return element( by.css( 'app-root app-login div.login-wrapper form.login section.title' ) )
      .getText() as Promise<string>;
  }
}
```

The html used to look like:

```
<div class="main-container">
...
</div>
```

and now it looks like:

```
<clr-main-container>
...
</clr-main-container>
```

The test is failing because it can't find the Clarity Module

```
...
1. If 'clr-main-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`
...
```

I can't seem to figure out how to tell the Protractor e2e tests to import modules (it is trivially easy with Karma unit tests)

Comment: Does it((browser.baseUrl) can view on the chrome browser without `Protractor` ? I think `Protractor` it doesn't need import `Clarity Module`

Comment: Can you load the application in the browser? Protractor doesn't setup Angular modules, it just loads URLs and tests the page. It seems like you should have the same problem in the browser, which would indicate that your page hasn't included the ClarityModule in your app (or feature module).